# How to ignore certificate errors in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, certificate, webclient

I have searched the internet and I know that in .Net we can use the following codes to ignore certification errors.

```
 ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
            new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(
                delegate
                { return true; }
            );
```

But the certification classes are not supported in windows phone 7 development (know from http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/4f795a8e-de05-4f01-be7f-0cf2be3a71c2). I am now using a `WebClient` to visit a `HTTPS` website which requires a certification first. So I am wondering is it possible to ignore the certification errors so that I can continue with my program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, unfortunately, the security guys won't let you.

Comment: Thank you. I finally used a HTTP website instead.

Answer (score 3):

Just make the connection to the same url but without the https

Example:

change this
https://qa.server.com/webservices/test

to this
http://qa.server.com/webservices/test

and it will work ;)

This is only assuming that the server you are calling does not require https.